# How to fix "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on yield

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, yield

I want to use a generator function while looping through an array to call an API function.

I tried using setTimeout but the function doesn't pause. It makes over 2500 call and causes CORS fetch API error.

```
function* subjectGenerator(){
    subjects.forEach(subject=>{
        let examyear =  startYear; 
        while (examyear <= endYear) {
            const api = createQuestionsURLApi(subject, examyear);
            // this.subject = subject.toLowerCase();
            getQuestionFromURL(api, subject);
            console.log(subject, api);
            yield examyear++;
        }

    });
}
```

I expect the yield to be accepted so I can use subjectGenerator.next() to loop through.

Comment: The issue is that you have `yield` in the `forEach` callback, not inside the generator. You should probably re-consider your approach here in total.

Comment: Maybe it's because the yield is inside a "normal" arrow function and not a generator function.

Comment: `yield` is acting upon the `forEach` callback function. Yield should be used outside the foreach. I mean, you shouldn't use the foreach at all, right there. Besides, I assume `startYear` is global. Finally, you should note that you're yielding the **previous** value of examyear, not sure whether that's the intended behavior. Also, are you trying to perform async operations inside the generator?

Comment: As a side note, reading again about _I want to use a generator function while looping through an array to call an API function._, keep in mind that **async** function generators are (as far as I rememebr) an ECMAScript 2018 (or ES9) proposal. Currently, `yield` does not work with async operations. I mean, it's not that it does not work, it just **won't** wait the operation to finish. Some "modern" editors will also warn you about that: http://prntscr.com/o5x894 . read more here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-async-generator-function-definitions

Comment: @briosheje, I'm calling some API. Hence for every time I make the call *synchronously*, I get CORS error. So I thought I could use yield and setTimeout to reduce how fast the request is sent to the server to avoid the error.

Comment: @Tino usually API calls are **asynchronous**. That said, you **can** do that by just removing the foreach and using a regular for. Just replace the foreach with `for (var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) { let subject = subjects[i]; // rest of the code }`. In that way, `yield` will work as intended. However, I may throw you some thougts about the fact that: 1) Usually, such requests are not sync. 2) Usually, CORS issues are **not** related to a function generator. In a nutshell, CORS is likely unrelated to that issue and you probably will need further analysis to solve that.

Comment: @briosheje. That's very correct. Exactly what I did.
Thanks for the info on CORS will work on that more.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @briosheje

```js
function* subjectGenerator(){
    for(let i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++){
        const subject = subjects[i];
        let examyear =  startYear; 
        while (examyear <= endYear) {
            const api = createQuestionsURLApi(subject, examyear);
            getQuestionFromURL(api, subject);
            console.log(subject, api);
            yield examyear++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done, you may accept your own aswer at this point, I'm glad this helped ;)

Comment: Thank you once more @briosheje. This is a paradigm shift on yield for me.

Comment: just a final side note: **beware of support for that**. I'm assuming it's a node application, hence you may remember that function generators are entirely supported with no issues since 6.4.0: https://node.green/#ES2015-functions-generators-basic-functionality (even earlier if you don't need all the functionalities).